# How to define an array of objects in OpenAPI 2.0?

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm new in using swaggerhub. I need to define an API, and the request needs to look like this json:

```
{
  "acountNumber": "1234564545444854",
  "warningTypes":[
    {
      "warningCode": 122,
      "warningMessage": "string message"
    }    
   ]  
}
```

At this moment I have this:

```
definitions:
  WarningCodes:
    type: object
    required:
    - accountNumber
    - warningCodes
    - messages
    properties:
      accountNumber:
        type: string
        example: 1234567890
      warningTypes:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            warningCode:
            type: integer
            warningMessage:
            type: string
```

Is not working in that way.

Comment: How exactly is this YAML not working? What result do you expect and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it requires a new entity, like this

```yaml
definitions:
  WarningCodes:
    type: object
    required:
    - accountNumber
    - warningCodes
    - messages
    properties:
      accountNumber:
        type: string
        example: '1234567890'

      warningTypes:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/WarningType'

  WarningType:
    type: object
    properties:
      warningCode:
        type: integer
        example: 122
      warningMessage:
        type: string
        minLength: 0
        maxLength: 256
        example: test1,test
```

Comment: was very successful, but I have an error message:

should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: components